# Recommendations for a Windows Media Centre substitute?

Tags: software-recommendation, media-manager

Are there any suggestions for media centre that can be used on Ubuntu 10.10? I need a media centre which works as same as the Windows Media Centre, but I can drop the online shows =)

Comment: Windows Media Center can deal with TV-Tuner cards. Do you need that functionality? Maybe you should update your question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should take a look at [Moovida](http://www.moovida.com/) [image: Install Moovida]

Comment: woah ! looks very nice , how can i install it using ppa?

Comment: Just look for "moovida" in the Software Center, you'll be able to install it easily.

Comment: hmm thx , gonna try it now

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) ([Ubuntu Install from PPA Instructions](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Installing_XBMC_for_Linux#Ubuntu)).  It has options for a live-cd install, or can be installed as an application on Ubuntu.  It is extremely configurable, but beautiful and functional out of the box.  Of course, it has full LIRC support.  It is skinnable, so can look like anything ranging from Windows Media Centre through to Apple's simplistic Front Row.

It supports "Series" information - put all your Grey's Anatomy episodes inside a "Grey's Anatomy" folder and tell XMBC that it's a TV show folder, XMBC will then scan the internet for information on the show, setting the folder up with a custom logo and cast information.  Similarly for any movies you have digital copies of.

It also support VDPAU, which will give Nvidia card owners full hardware acceleration.  This is crucial for boxes like the Acer Revo ([Google product search](http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?complete=0&hl=en&biw=1189&bih=778&q=acer+revo&safe=active&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=8262168205230543916&ei=IGzFTOStHMXL4Abcn7G6Aw&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ8wIwAA#)), which features Nvidia's ION chipset - without VDPAU support, that device's Atom processor wouldn't be capable of 1080p output.

It doesn't integrate any form of live TV to my knowledge, so if you need to integrate your tv-tuner card, then you're better of with perhaps MythTV or Mythbuntu instead.

Comment: I tried MythTV over a year ago and ran away screaming after seeing how I had to be a technical genius to configure the TV tuner card - there were all kinds of parameters to be set, I have no idea. Has MythTV gained some sort of tuner-plug-and-play in the meantime?

Comment: Like you, I'm not a MythTV fan.  But it's one of the few options if you want TV integration.

Answer (score 4):

Why not **Boxee**? You can find it [here](http://www.boxee.tv/), download is possible after registration, both 32 and 64 bit debs are available.

Comment: Last time I checked, they had a version that has dependencies that are not in Ubuntu 10.10. But there is a solution in their forums! Boxee is imho the best mediacenter.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely the best, even if it requires a good computer. I don't know about Maverick compatibility, with Lucid and before everything was fine. I will give it a try.

Comment: You can find a deb modified by me here (http://ubuntuone.com/p/M9n/), you can install it on Maverick, on my pc it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you require TV checkout [MythTV](http://www.mythtv.org/), if not [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/). Depending on your hardware, you may decide that you want to avoid using a window manager entirely. You should probably do some research...

Comment: XBMC is awesome. They also have a Live-CD so you can easily try it without installing anything. The upcoming version has a builtin Add-On systems that allows you to download and install new Skins and Add-Ons (e.g. for Youtube) very easily.

Comment: [Mythbuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mythbuntu) is an official Ubuntu derivative that you could check out.