# Windows media center alternatives

Tags: software-recommendation, multimedia, video-player

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Media Centre options?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9329/media-centre-options)

Hello, anyone know about Windows Media Center alternative for ubuntu? I want to play my all video, music and show my images with just one app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xmbc is a great alternative. Before I switched to Ubuntu, I had been using it even on Windows in place of the Media Center.

http://xbmc.org/

Answer (score 1):

A program that I find extraordinary from both design and usability points of view is: Boxee.

Comment: Jim Cass? Is that you?